# how to mapping an OneToMany relation with Weak Entity in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I need to map a OneToMany relationship in hibernate, with the JPA annotations, in which is involved a weak entity.
For example
Table orders:

```
CREATE TABLE orders(
idorder serial NOT NULL,
note varchar(30),
CONSTRAINT orders_pkey PRIMARY KEY (idorder)
)
```

Table OrderItems:

```
CREATE TABLE orderitems(
  idorder integer NOT NULL,
  iditem serial NOT NULL,
  qnt integer,
  CONSTRAINT orderitems_pk PRIMARY KEY (idorder, iditem),
  CONSTRAINT fk_orderitems FOREIGN KEY (idorder)
      REFERENCES orders (idorder) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Within my class "Orders" I have realized the method getOrderItem() in this way:

```
// i need cascadeType.All here
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "order")
public Set<OrderItem> getOrderItems() {
    return items;
}
```

now,
not being able to know the identifier that will be assigned to a new order
prior to insertion, such as Annotations can I use within the class OrderItem in order to submit automatically (in cascade mode) the correct idOrder?
my goal is to get a situation like this.

```
Order myOrder = new Order();
//      myOrder.setId(1) not necessary
myOrder.setNote("orderNote");

OrderItem firstItem = new OrderItem();  
// firstItem.setIdOrder()       no need to specify idorder
// firstItem.setId(12);
firstItem.setName("firstItem");
firstItem.setQnt(2);

OrderItem secondItem = new OrderItem();
// secondItem.setId(13);
secondItem.setName("secondItem");
secondItem.setQnt(4);

Set<OrderItem> items = new HashSet<OrderItem>();
items.add(firstItem);
items.add(secondItem);

myOrder.setItems(items);

OrderDAO dao = new OrderDAO();
dao.save(myOrder);  // i want inser all items in cascade with the idOder assigned to "myOrder"
```

Comment: In your case you should  go through this tutorial  http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Ok I will try to add Entity classes you need to have above given scenario.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
public class Order{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="note ")
    private String note ;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="orders")
    private Set<OrderItem> orderitems;

    // Getter and Setter methods
}
```

And then the OrderItem class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="OrderItems")
public class OrderItem{

    @Id
    @Column(name="iditem")
    private Long iditem;

    @Column(name="qnt")
    private long qnt ;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idorder")
    private Order order;

    public OrderItem() {

    }

    // Getter and Setter methods
}
```

Also i dint get which column your setname maps to.. and iditem isnt generated value its assigned id type
Ok then it also could be issue about *inverse* that who could be the relationship owener .. Inverse=true  is same behaviour as *mappedBy* attribute usage so try changing it..
Let me know if this works or you get a issue while trying this out..

Comment: thank you.
Unfortunately, even in this way I can fix it.
does not insert any value within the range OrderItems.idLibro

Comment: @Pierock does it give any exception?? and what is idLibro you mentioned it first time..?

Comment: currently with this configuration, running the command
    dao.save (my Order)        , I get:
<pre>
- Hibernate: 
    /* insert comp.Order */ insert 
        into  public.orders (note) values (?)
- Hibernate: 
    /* update comp.OrderItem */ update
            public.orderItems 
        set qnt=? 
        where iditem=?</pre>
**org.hibernate.StaleStateException**: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Comment: StaleStateException usually caused when the hibernate can't find all the rows it needs to update. Meaning that when you try to update some objects that were pulled from the DB they don't really exist. Also make a try to use save and update separately and using saveorupdate may be that gives us a clue..

Comment: in fact I do not know why the update starts.
my instruction is exactly what I described in my post, and at present the tables Orders and OrderItems my db are both empty.

Comment: @Pierock it is because saveorupdate uses id as parameter to decide whether to save or update.. if id is equal to unsaved value to null then save is called or else update is called..

Comment: @Pierock so you avoid saveorupdate or use _@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)_ for OrderItem class..

Comment: I have noticed one thing that might be a good clue.
if you start from OrderItems instead of Order. cascade works well. i.e: myOrderItem.setOrder(myOrder); dao_orderItem.save(myOrderItem); in this case the inserts are corretc. what needs to be corrected in order to start from "Order"?

Comment: Ok then it also could be issue about _inverse_ that who could be the relationship owner .. Inverse=true  is same behaviour as _mappedBy_ attribute usage so try changing it..

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to guarantee that the pair (iditem, order) is unique.